# How to translate rows in a column using textblob

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, translation

I have a jupyter dataframe with 10,000 rows in pashto that I want to translate to english in an adjacent column.  There are actually 2 columns that I want to translate they would be "description" and "text". and next to each of those columns  I want new columns with the translation that are called "Description_Translated" and "Text_Translated".  Keep in mind that I want to do this using textblob.  Also the text below is just for sytnax its not the real text but gives the idea.

Description                    Description_Translated     Text                Text_Translated

د کب نیولو قواوې چې                                                   کب نیول
انګریزانو ته یې د کاسټ پر لیکه 
خورا ډیر کنټرول ورکړ.

د پیسو مینځ ته                                                  کب نیولو
راوړل شوي راډونه عام شوي

Comment: What problem do you have? What output do you expect from the question? Code or solution?

Comment: want to show translation per row